# Problems attempting to import a jsm resource: AddonManager

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, jsm

I have a function in my Greasemonkey Script to access the Firefox [AddonManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager) API. According to my log statements, though, I can never actually import it.

```
function getScripts() {
  console.log("step 1");
  Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");  
  console.log("step 2");
  AddonManager.getAddonsByTypes(["greasemonkey-user-script"], function(a) {
    var arr = []
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = a[i].name;
      console.log(arr[i]);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do, but that code will never run in/from a Greasemonkey script.  You need to code an add-on or WebExtension to access that API.

Comment: For this part, just listing the currently installed Add-Ons. Why can't this API be accessed from a script?

Comment: Because Greasemonkey doesn't expose that part of the API.  Greasemonkey is *built* with the API, it is not the API itself.